# How can I bind the visibility of a StackPane to a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, visibility

I have a few StackPanes that I only want to display for a specific value of a ComboBox. I've gotten the property to change as I want it to, but for some reason, the StackPane visibility doesn't update when the ComboBox value does. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

RegisteredServersView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.Servers.RegisteredServersView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Servers"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="250" Width="600">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:RegisteredServersViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Server Instance:" Margin="30,10,10,10"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ServerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                     Width="140" Margin="10">
                <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Authorization Type:" Margin="10"/>
            <ComboBox Name="cbAuthType" 
                      Margin="10" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Types}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding AuthType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      Width="141"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Visibility="{Binding Vis}">
            <Label Content="Login:" Margin="80,10,10,10"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Login, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                     Width="140" Margin="10">
                <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Visibility="{Binding Vis}">
            <Label Content="Password:" Margin="60,10,10,10"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                     Width="140" Margin="10">
                <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="Reg"
                    Content="Register"
                    Click="OnSave"
                    Margin="145,10,10,10"
                    Width="60"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonEnabled, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>

            <Button x:Name="Cancel"
                    Content="Cancel"
                    Click="OnCancel"
                    Margin="5,10,10,10"
                    Width="60"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

RegisteredServersView.xaml.cs

```
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1.Servers
{ 
    public partial class RegisteredServersView : UserControl
    {
        public RegisteredServersView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new RegisteredServersViewModel();
            cbAuthType.SelectedItem = cbAuthType.Items[0];
        }

        public void OnCancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)VisualParent.GetSelfAndAncestors().FirstOrDefault(a => a is Window);
            window.Close();
        }

        public void OnSave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnCancel(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

RegisteredServersViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WpfApp1.Data;
using WpfApp1.Repos;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1.Servers
{
    public class RegisteredServersViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private readonly RegisteredServerValidator _validator;
        private string _serverName;
        private string _authType;
        private string _login;
        private string _password;

        private Visibility _vis;

        public IEnumerable<string> _types;

        public RegisteredServersViewModel()
        {
            _types = new List<string>() { "SQLAuth", "Integrated" };
            _validator = new RegisteredServerValidator();
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> Types
        {
            get { return _types; }
        }

        public string ServerName
        {
            get { return _serverName; }
            set
            {
                _serverName = value;
                CheckButtonEnabled();
                OnPropertyChanged("ServerName");
            }
        }

        public string AuthType
        {
            get { return _authType; }
            set
            {
                _authType = value;

                if(value.Equals("SQLAuth"))
                {
                    Vis = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    Vis = Visibility.Hidden;
                }

                CheckButtonEnabled();
                OnPropertyChanged("AuthType");
            }
        }


        public Visibility Vis
        {
            get { return _vis; }
            private set
            { 
                _vis = value;
                Console.WriteLine(_vis);
                OnPropertyChanged("Vis");
            }
        }

        public string Login
        {
            get { return _login; }
            set
            {
                _login = value;
                CheckButtonEnabled();
                OnPropertyChanged("Login");
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                CheckButtonEnabled();
                OnPropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                var firstOrDefault = _validator.Validate(this).Errors.FirstOrDefault(lol => lol.PropertyName == columnName);
                if(firstOrDefault != null)
                {
                    return _validator != null ? firstOrDefault.ErrorMessage : "";
                }
                return "";
            }
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get
            {
                if(_validator != null)
                {
                    var results = _validator.Validate(this);
                    if(results != null && results.Errors.Any())
                    {
                        var errors = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
                        return errors;
                    }
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private bool _buttonEnabled;

        public bool ButtonEnabled
        {
            get { return _buttonEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _buttonEnabled = value;
                //Console.WriteLine(_buttonEnabled);
                OnPropertyChanged("ButtonEnabled");
            }
        }

        public void CheckButtonEnabled()
        {
            if(ServerName != null && AuthType.Equals("SQLAuth") && Login != null && Password != null)
            {
                ButtonEnabled = true;
            }
            else if(ServerName != null && !AuthType.Equals("SQLAuth"))
            {
                ButtonEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ButtonEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

RegisteredServerValidator.cs

```
using FluentValidation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WpfApp1.Data;
using WpfApp1.Servers;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    class RegisteredServerValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisteredServersViewModel>
    {
        public RegisteredServerValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(instance => instance.ServerName)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("This field cannot be left blank.");

            RuleFor(instance => instance.Login)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("This field cannot be left blank.");

            RuleFor(instance => instance.Password)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("This field cannot be left blank");
        }
    }
}
```

INotifyPropertyChanged.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class INotifyPropertyChanged : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val,
            [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(member, val)) return;
            member = val;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    }
}
```

RegisteredServersWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Servers.RegisteredServersWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Servers"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      Height="300" Width="500"
      Title="Registered Servers">

    <!--This contains the UserControl with the form.-->
    <Grid>
        <local:RegisteredServersView HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

RegisteredServersWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1.Servers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for RegisteredServersWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class RegisteredServersWindow : Window
    {
        public RegisteredServersWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried using the Visibilty class instead of boolean and was unable to get that to work either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Side note, since you are defining Vis yourself it doesn't have to be a boolean, it could be a Visibility, and then you won't need the converter.

Comment: cbAuthType is populated in the constructor for the view. I have a separate class that defines the values as an enum.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Thanks, that seems like a significantly easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the code from my "test project" into the actual one and suddenly it works. Not sure what changed, but it's functioning now. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score -2):

I would subscribe to the comboboxe's [SelectionChange Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1) and flip the status there.